# Can we say that a system of $n-1$ linear equations in $n$ variables always has infinite solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

For example , let's say we have $2$ linear equations in $3$ variables , i.e. , 
$a_1x + b_1 y +  c_1z = 0 $, and 
$a_2x + b_2 y +  c_2 z =0 $, 
now here for each value of $z$ we will have $2$ linear equations in $2$ variables and hence unique values of $x$ and $y $. Now since $z$ can take an infinite number of values  and for each value we will have unique values of $x$ and $y $. So can we conclude that, a system of $n-1$ linear equations in $n$ variables will always have an infinite number of solutions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+y+z=0\\x+y+z=1\end{array}\right.$$has no solutions.

However, if you are talking about *homogeneous* linear equations (that is, equations of the type $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots+a_nx_n=0$), then you are right: a system with less than $n$ of those equations in $n$ variables always has infinitely many solutions. Actually, the set of solutions is a vector space whose dimension is greater than $0$.

Comment: By system of equations I mean 2 different equations .

Comment: those *are* two different equations

Comment: @Sameernilkhan One could hide the similarity of the equations more by using a system of three or more equations but the general idea and answer would be the same.

Comment: Ok I mean equations without any constants i.e. equations will only have variables and their coefficients.

Comment: Such as… ? ${}$

Comment: such as , I have written in the body of my question.

Comment: In the body of your question there is the constant $0$, right?!

Comment: Ok finally the equation should not have any other constant than zero .

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?